# Finding the lower bound using Chebyshev's theorem

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

> If the probability density of $X$ is given by
>   $$f(x)= \begin{cases}
> 630x^4(1-x)^4&& \text{for } 0 <x<1\\ 
>  0 && \text{elsewhere.}\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   Find the probability that it will take on a value within two standard deviations of the mean and compare this probability with the lower-bounded provided by Chebyshev's theorem.

Let $\sigma$ be the standard deviation and $\mu$ be the mean.

How does one find the variance? $\sigma^2$. I know one must use the formula $\sigma^2= \mu^{'}_{2}-\mu^{2}$

In order to solve this one must integrate.

= $\int 630x^4(1-x)^4dx$

I cannot go any further than this as I do not know how to find the upper and lowerbounds.

**EDIT** After doing some extensive math I figured out that

$\mu = .5$ because

$\mu = \int^{1}_{0} x\cdot630x^4(1-x)^4 dx = .5$

$\mu_{2} =\int_0^1 x^2\cdot630x^4(1-x)^4dx= \frac{3}{11}$

$\sigma^2= \mu_{2}-u^{2} = \frac{3}{11}-(\frac{1}{2})^2=.0227 \rightarrow \sqrt{.0227} =  .20 \text{ or } .15$

So

$\int_{.20} 630x^4(1-x)^4$

Now in order to finish the problem we must find what the upperbound is and this where I am lost.

**Chebyshev’s Theorem**

If $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and the standard
deviation of a random variable X, then for any positive constant
k the probability is at least $1- \frac{1}{k^2}$ that X will take on a value within k standard deviations of the mean; symbolically

$$P(|x-\mu|<k \sigma) \ge 1- \frac{1}{k^2}, \sigma \neq 0$$

**Proof**

$$\sigma^2 = E[(X-\mu)^2] = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (x-\mu)^2f(x)dx$$

[image]

Diagram for Chebyshev’s theorem.

Then dividing the integral into three parts as shown above

$$\sigma^2 = \int^{\mu-k\sigma}_{-\infty} (x-\mu)^2f(x)dx+ \int^{\mu + k\sigma}_{\mu-k\sigma}(x-\mu)^2f(x)dx+\int^{\infty}_{\mu+k\sigma} (x-\mu)^2f(x)dx$$

Since the integrand $(x-\mu)^2f(x)$ is nonnegative we can from the inequality

$$\sigma^2 \ge \int^{\mu-k\sigma}_{-\infty} (x-\mu)^2f(x)dx+\int^{\infty}_{\mu+k \sigma} (x-\mu)^2f(x)dx $$

by deleting the second integral. Therefore since $(x-\mu)^2 \ge k^2\sigma^2 \text{ for } x \le \mu -k\sigma \text{ or }  x \ge \mu+k\sigma \text{ it follows that }$

$$(\sigma)^2 \ge \int^{\mu-k\sigma}_{-\infty} k^2\sigma^2f(x)dx+\int^{\infty}_{\mu+k\sigma} k^2\sigma^2f(x)dx$$

and hence that

$$\frac{1}{k^2} \ge \int^{\mu-k\sigma}_{-\infty} f(x)dx+ \int^{\infty}_{\mu+k\sigma}f(x)dx$$

provide $\sigma^2 \neq 0$ Since the sum of the two integrals on the right-hand side
is the probability that X will take on a value less than or equal to $\mu-k\sigma$
or greater than or equal to $\mu+k\sigma$, we have thus shown that

$$P(|X-\mu| \ge k\sigma) \le \frac{1}{k^2}$$

and it follows that

$$P(|X-\mu| \lt k\sigma) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: The mean is $\int_0^1 x(630x^4(1-x)^4 dx$. The mean of the square is $\int_0^1 x^2(630x^4(1-x)^4) dx$.

Comment: @user1952009 any suggestions on your thoughts are wholeheartedly welcomed the quicker this thing is done the more I can do to be the best.

Comment: @LittleJon I meant read [the description of the  (chebyshev-function) tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/chebyshev-function/info), you'll see it isn't related to your question

Comment: @user1952009 It seemed right at the time.... Anyway do you know what Max meant at the bottom of comments I think he might be on to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the usual formulas.
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\, = \int_{0}^1 xf(x)\,dx\\
E[X^2] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1x^2 f(x)\,dx
\end{align*}
where the second equality in both lines is true because the pdf is "$0$ elsewhere". I leave the integration to you. Finally
$$\operatorname{Var}[X] = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2.$$

---

You found that $E[X] = \frac{1}{2} =\mu$, $E[X^2] = \frac{3}{11}$, and $\text{Var}[X] = \frac{1}{44} = \sigma^2$

Then the exercise asks for $P(|X-\mu|< 2\sigma)$.
\begin{align*}
P(|X-\mu|<2\sigma)&= P(-2\sigma<X-\mu<2\sigma)\\
&= P(-2\sigma+\mu<X<2\sigma+\mu)\\
&= \int_{-2\sigma+\mu}^{2\sigma+\mu} 630x^4(1-x)^4\,dx \tag 1\\
&= 0.962071
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is true by the definition of pdf.
The theorem gives
$$P(|X-\mu|<2\sigma) \geq 1-\frac{1}{2^2} = \frac{3}{4}.$$